# Создать функцию - конструктор для объектов типа Post

Tags: javascript, node.js

Создать функцию - конструктор для объектов типа Post.

Функция-конструктор должна принимать следующие аргументы:

1. id
2. title
3. content

Добавьте через прототип метод preview, который возвращает первое предложение из поля content. Конец предложения определяется по символу .(точка).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Используем дефолтные параметры, если один из аргументов (или все) не переданы
function Post(id = 1, title = 'Example title', content = 'Hello world') {
  this.id = id;
  this.title = title;
  this.content = content;
}

Post.prototype.preview = function preview() {
  // разбиваем строку на массив строк, где разделитель точка
  const [ firstSentence ] = this.content.split('.');
  return firstSentence;
}

const post1 = new Post(1, 'first title', 'Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum Two');
console.log(post1);
console.log(post1.preview());

const post2 = new Post();
console.log(post2);
console.log(post2.preview());
```